# I am begginer with mysql connection with netbeans

Tags: netbeans-8, mysql-5.7

When I click on start on Database, it shows error like ZeroDataTimeBehaviour. I tried everything but I did not get the solution since I am new to mysql and its connectivity. Mysql works properly in command line but I don't know how to connect with netbeans properly ?

[Error on click on start on netbeans](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8WSq.png)

Answer (score 1):

First of all I would try with this setting:

[image]

If that doesn't help to You try to lower version of mySql to 5.5

You might find this link helpful: [NetBeans](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/install-and-configure-mysql-server.html), [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html)

> zeroDateTimeBehavior
>
> What should happen when the driver encounters DATETIME values that are
>   composed entirely of zeros (used by MySQL to represent invalid dates)?
>   Valid values are "exception", "round" and "convertToNull".
>
> Default: exception
>
> Since version: 3.1.4